# Trying to downsize a dataframe by increasing the timestep in R

Tags: r

I have a column which records time in milliseconds starting at 0 and uniformly increasing by .001. I would like to downsize my dataframe by creating a new dataframe that only records the rows that occur every ten milliseconds.

My problem is that the data is in long format and not all participants took the same amount of time to complete the task, so I cannot just take every 10th row.

To try and clarify, this means that whenever there is  0.000 in the time column,  I would like to record this point in the new dataframe and then restart the process of taking every tenth millisecond.  So far I have tried using "filter" and "subset" with no success.

This is a small example of the data I have:

| ID | Time | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.000 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 0.001 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 0.002 | 3 | 15 |
| 1 | 0.003 | 4 | 20 |
| 1 | 0.004 (on so on... until 0.052) | ... | ... |
| 1 | 0.053 | 10 | 25 |
| 2 | 0.000 | 30 | 30 |
| 2 | 0.001 | 35 | 35 |
| 2 | 0.002 (on so on...until 0.036) | ... | ... |
| 2 | 0.037 | 50 | 55 |
| 3 | 0.000 | 55 | 50 |

And this is what I would like:

| ID | Time | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.000 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 0.010 | 30 | 40 |
| 1 | 0.020 | 35 | 45 |
| 1 | 0.030 | 30 | 40 |
| 1 | 0.040 | 33 | 44 |
| 1 | 0.050 | 60 | 100 |
| 2 | 0.000 | 30 | 30 |
| 2 | 0.010 | 40 | 40 |
| 2 | 0.020 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 0.030 | 60 | 60 |
| 3 | 0.000 | 55 | 50 |

Comment: I added a simple example table to try and help.  Apologies, I am quite new to coding in general and I feel like if I posted my attempts so far it could create more confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `subset` + `ave` + `duplicated` like below

```
subset(
  df,
  !ave(Time, ID, FUN = function(x) duplicated(ceiling(seq_along(x) / 10)))
)
```

which gives

```
   ID Time
1   1 0.00
11  1 0.01
21  1 0.02
31  1 0.03
41  1 0.04
51  1 0.05
55  2 0.00
65  2 0.01
75  2 0.02
85  2 0.03
92  3 0.00
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), Time = c(0,
0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009,
0.01, 0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.014, 0.015, 0.016, 0.017, 0.018,
0.019, 0.02, 0.021, 0.022, 0.023, 0.024, 0.025, 0.026, 0.027,
0.028, 0.029, 0.03, 0.031, 0.032, 0.033, 0.034, 0.035, 0.036,
0.037, 0.038, 0.039, 0.04, 0.041, 0.042, 0.043, 0.044, 0.045, 
0.046, 0.047, 0.048, 0.049, 0.05, 0.051, 0.052, 0.053, 0, 0.001,
0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01,
0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.014, 0.015, 0.016, 0.017, 0.018, 0.019,
0.02, 0.021, 0.022, 0.023, 0.024, 0.025, 0.026, 0.027, 0.028,
0.029, 0.03, 0.031, 0.032, 0.033, 0.034, 0.035, 0.036, 0)), row.names = c(NA,
-92L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @ThomasIsCoding , thanks for the help. I tested your solution and get the following error: `Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors` This is my fault  as I omitted that are also two other columns in the dataset for brevity as I did not expect them to be relevant.

Comment: @Sean Sorry for my typo. Please retry it with my update